# "textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:" not called with Chinese keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview, chinese-locale, uitextviewdelegate

I have a `UITextView`which I use for typing message and modifying the text for tagging people. I use the `-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` delegate method to detect changes and modify the text, which works perfectly fine in English. Now when I use a Chinese keyboard, the delegate method doesn't even get called when a Chinese word/character is inserted.

Is this a known issue? Or I have to do configure something to make it work?

FYI the Chinese keyboard (pinyin) works somehow similar to auto-correct in which it suggests a word based on english characters you type. When I tap on the suggestions, the delegate method is not called.

Comment: i got the same problem , did u found the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But I haven't tested it in iOS 9. Does it still appear in iOS 9?

Comment: YES，my solution is use  shouldChangeTexInRange & TextViewDidChange at the same time , seems work